# How can I implement a "double" UITextField?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am trying to generate a UITextField in a view like this. I don't mind using IB or doing it programmatically.

[image]
<sub>(source: [echofon.com](http://echofon.com/img/twitter/iphone/setup.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. New File(Cocoa Touch Class -> UIViewController subclass)
   UITableViewController subclass, With XIB for interface(check both)
2. open Xib file
3. change the view style(plain->group) on Attributes Inspector(apple key + 1)
4. add following code in .m file

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Username";
        UITextField *field = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(120, 10, 180, 30)] autorelease];
        [cell addSubview:field];

    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Password";
        UITextField *field = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(120, 10, 180, 30)] autorelease];
        field.secureTextEntry = YES;
        [cell addSubview:field];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

```
- (NSString *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section 
{
    return @"Account";
}
```

```
- (NSString *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView
titleForFooterInSection: (NSInteger)section 
{
    return @"If you don't have a twitter account, go to twitter.com to sign up.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the UITextField objects inside of a table to achieve this effect. See UITableView for more details: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html